# delete whole row after x mins in mysql db and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to setup a sql db where users must confirm their email address. I'm wondering if there is a way to auto delete the users in the sql db that attempted to register (submit their info) but not confirm their email address after x amount of mins.

the script that i have written inserts their info straight into the db and then updates a column on the db to "ACTIVE" once the users has confirmed, so i don't insert the data once they have activated, but before with a status of "NON_ACTIVE". Then when they confirm their email address, that status turns to "ACTIVE".

so if a users submits their info, but fails to confirm their email address, their details are still in the DB. I need something that will auto delete a row with the status "NON_ACTIVE" after x minutes to when they submitted their info. I have another column in the DB with their exact submit time and date.

any ideas?

Comment: there is no way to auto perform this. you need cronjob/scheduler help with the prune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a statement similar to @Lars:

```
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE (mailsent < NOW() - INTERVAL @x MINUTE)
  AND (state = 'NON_ACTIVE')
```

but you don't need to have a cron job or a trigger for this. Just put it in one of the PHP pages your users access (perhaps the Login or Register page?). It may even be set not to run every time but say, once for every hundred Logins if you don't mind some records get deleted a few seconds or minutes later.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. Just a quick question.. Where you have written "mailsent", that would be the column of which stores the date and time of when the user submitted info? and the "@x" should be replaced with how many mins the user has to confirm? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The SQL would be `DELETE FROM users WHERE (now() - mailsent) > (120*60) AND state = "NON_ACTIVE"`, where *users* is the table name, *mailsent* the timestamp of the mailsending and 120 the number of minutes you want as a timeout.

You can just run this command via a cronjob on a linux system with `cron -e someUser` and entering the following line

```
* * * * * mysql myDatabase < 'DELETE FROM users WHERE (now() - mailsent) > (120*60) AND state = "NON_ACTIVE"'
```

This will run the command every minute. Please note, that your *someUser* has to be able to access the mysql-database without a password, e.g. by putting the password into [$HOME/.my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/option-files.html)

Comment: You're not limited to run cronjobs as root, it might even be a good idea to let cronjobs for the db run as some nonprivileged user.  Same goes for the mysql user, better to create a user for this kind of jobs that's trusted if local.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. Where would i place that code? I'm new to SQL DB's and was weirdly hoping there could be a way to use php to do it. I wont bother with the cronjob as I'm not using a linux system. I have MySQL WorkBench setup (if thats required). I'm guessing that code needs to go in "Triggers" field? Thanks mate!

Comment: On a windows machine, you can also add scheduled jobs under `Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks`. Save the mysql-query above in a file *\path\to\example.sql* and add a new scheduled task with `mysql.exe` (usually somewhere in c:\Program Files\Mysql\5.0\) and the argument '-e "\path\to\example.sql -D myDatabase". Schedule the job for running each minute and you'll have the same as a cronjob. Your welcome (gimme reputation ;) )!

Comment: @Nav "bother"?  You'll need some facility to run that code on a regular basis, if you're using Windows you should look for some other task scheduler - it's a really crucial bit of infrastructure for any kind for server setup.

Comment: Thing is, I'm on shared host (GoDaddy), so i don't think i can do stuff like that. Am I screwed? Thanks (I gave you rep btw xD)

Comment: @Nav according to the feature matrix here http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=9009 all godaddy linux plans allow cron jobs.  Windows plans apparently lack that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Store the create time for the row in a new column.

Have another script (called by cron?) or part of your other site code periodically delete any/all rows in the table with Status="NON_ACTIVE", which were created more than X minutes ago.

Psudeo-sql: Delete from UserTable Where (status="NON_ACTIVE" And (Minutes(now()-createdate))>30);

Two jobs attempting to delete the same record is a possible race condition, but not really bad.

Comment: AWESOME! I already have the date and time info in a different row. But the column is called "date_reg". Where would that column be defined in the code you just provided? thanks!

Comment: also, how will this script run automatically? Looks like something that I'll have to run?

Comment: Use something like cron, like @Lars described.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a database at all. Just ask a user for their email, send a verification link and start registration only after getting this link clicked.

Comment: That would work, but it could put a few users off. If they just see an email address field for something they were expecting to require allot more info, its a bad impression. Looks like i just want their email... thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a mysql event ?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

```
CREATE EVENT delete_event
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO BEGIN
      DELETE messages WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END;
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time)