# Most efficient method to expire records after 10 minutes from creation

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a password recovery system that allows users to recover their password by email. The details for each request are inserted into my `recoveries` table, and are deleted upon successful recoveries. I have a timestamp for each recovery that is set 10 minutes after the creation of each recovery.

I want to implement a system that will automatically delete each expired recovery after 10 minutes. Since this expiry time will be different for every row, it means that using a cron job would be incredibly ineffective in performing this task.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
$time = time();
$recoveries = DB::fetch("DELETE FROM `recoveries` WHERE `expiry` <= ?;", array($time));
```

Comment: take reference from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time

Comment: I'd personally leave the record in the table and add a condition to the login with a recovered password to match your 10 minutes delay. Then add a cron task for house cleaning each day at night to clean up outdated entries.

Comment: @satishrajak When am I supposed to run that code though?

Comment: you can run this code once in your mysql database its will automatically in every 10 minutes

Comment: Do I just run that code in the SQL console in Phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way to do this is to use a view.  Huh?  What does that have to do with the problem?  Well, don't do the delete 10 minutes after wards.  Instead, create a view with the following logic:

```
create view v_recoveries as
    select r.*
    from recoveries r
    where expiry > date_sub(now(), interval 10 minutes);
```

For performance, you want an index on `recoveries(expiry)`, so this should be fast.

Then, at your leisure -- once per date, or once per hour, or once per week -- delete unneeded records with:

```
DELETE FROM `recoveries`
    WHERE `expiry` <= date_sub(now(), interval 10 minutes);
```

This approach has several advantages:

- The presence of data is exactly 10 minutes, rather than based on the scheduling of some job.
- The actual deletions can take place when the system is quiescent.
- If a cron job fails to execute, the data is not "corrupted" -- that is, you do not get data that is too old.
- If the system is busy (lots of inserts), then the inserts are not competing with deletes, further slowing the system down.

Comment: Best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trigger function at mysql level, when an entry will be inserted/updated, it will trigger the function, that will remove all entries(or entries older then 10 minutes) for this particular user.
This way you don't have to check every 1 minute (cron job) to see the entries to get deleted from the database (will make your life easy and will save some resources.)

You can also implement this technique when any person logged in (if you don't want to use triggers at mysql level)

Comment: But what about the last entry, for deletion it has to wait until some next entry arrives.....