# Create a MySQL event that efficiently deletes rows exactly 10 minutes after creation

Tags: php, mysql, events, cron

I have a password recovery system that allows users to recover their password. These requests are stored in the `recoveries` table. This table contains timestamps in the `expiry` column that state the time of each row's creation.

I want this event to run individually for every new row in `recoveries`, so that they expire *exactly* 10 minutes after creation.

I have this code, but I don't know how to make it run exactly 10 minutes after the creation of *each individual row* in `recoveries`:

```
CREATE EVENT `delete_recoveries`
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO BEGIN
      DELETE FROM `recoveries` WHERE `expiry` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
END;
```

Comment: This is pretty close to being a duplicate of your previous question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457483/most-efficient-method-to-expire-records-after-10-minutes-from-creation/29457896#29457896.  You really don't want an event firing off every 10 minutes after something happens.  This is not the best solution.

Comment: Yes but no one provided me with a good answer. What else am I supposed to do if this isn't the right solution?

Comment: You got an excellent answer to the other question that meets your needs including the arbitrary exactly 10 minute cutoff, but also does it very efficiently.  You should go back and re-read it until you understand why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem here is that you're using the wrong tool for the job. What you really need is a [queueing system](http://queues.io/).

Change your design just a bit. Instead of putting all the work in your database, make your application layer add things to the queue, and check it periodically for jobs to do. Most queues live in memory, so reading is really fast, and with many of them you can add a delay until an item is visible on the queue.

Alternatively, use a cron job to check your database, where you basically do something every ten minutes.