# Delete Row at Set Time

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a database table where rows need to be removed after a set time. That time is defined in minutes by the `valid_time` cell in that row. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096493/2179057) though I am not sure how I can implement what I need to into it.

Is someone able to tell me how I can implement this time (as minutes) into the event in the previous answer or if it's not possible, another way to do so. Thanks.

Clarification, I have two columns in the table. One is `created` which is a TIMESTAMP of when the row is created, and the second is `valid_time`, an integer in minutes of how long the row is valid for.

Comment: What database are you using ? What have you tried yet ?

Comment: @Mendez I'm using MySQL and I haven't tried anything as I've got no idea how to do it. It's mainly the minutes part I'm concerned about.

Comment: `valid time` (if that's an integer column menaing minuted froim now) is a bad design decision, database records are supposed to be context-free use a timestamp column `valid_until` iunstead, or in combination.

Comment: Then M0rtiis has an answer. arrange to run that delete command every minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `valid_time` MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the MySQL event scheduler and attach a DELETE query to it. That DELETE will be a simple query that will delete all records where `current_time` is greater that the `valid_time`/`valid_until` fields.

You can configure the scheduler to run in a minute/hourly/daily/... basis as you wish to erase the registers.

Check [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) for more information. `M0rtiis` offered the query example.