# Android CountDown Timer from Mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an Android app in which i want to do a count down timer which takes the time from MySQL once the **time gets over the particular record in MySQL should be deleted**.
I new to Android and MySQL so how can i do this with MySQL can anyone provide me some examples or tutorials regarding this.
I have tried searching in many websites but i didn't get any good tutorials.

Comment: and what you tried so far ?

Comment: can you post the code what you tried

Comment: Did u read my question first?

Comment: yes i read it...you can't get code for your entire requirement.First go through the counttimer and webservices.After that you got an idea to acheive this.i don't think so this requirement is too complicated.

Comment: If u can help me then tell me the solutions.

Comment: i didn't ask u for coding i just asked u for some good examples or tutorials only:)

Comment: first get a date from webservices .then raise broadcastreceiver in that particular time .When the time reach broadcast receiver will call.Within the broadcast receiver request an server to delete the particular data using intent service..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a sql script like this and the script have to be processed after some particular time.

```
CREATE EVENT delete_event
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO BEGIN
      DELETE messages WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time)

Study on Cronjob

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmBjg1nD5yA

You'll get a clear idea about it

Comment: thanks dude i have to use this in php script

Comment: exactly bro! i added a cronjob tutorial link too . You'll find a lot of tutorials on youtube :)