# Remove a record after 24 hour since it has been created

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2012 to create a table :

```
CREATE TABLE Account 
(
    Id          IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Email       NVARCHAR(64),
    Password    NVARCHAR(16),
    Created     DateTime
)
```

All I want to is :

- Run a query to delete the Account after 24 hour since it **has been created**.
- For example : At 8.am this morning, I create an account, I want my sql to trigger a query at 8.am tomorrow morning to delete the account.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: you forgot to post your attempt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a MySQL record after a certain time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time

Comment: Before asking a question try to search and make sure your question is unique

Comment: About http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time, I want my sql catch the record creation and trigger the query after 24 hour.

For example, at 8.am , I created a record, if the account is not activated till 8.am of tomorrow morning, it will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use datediff

```
delete from
account
where datediff(hour,createddate,getdate())>=24
```

Comment: the question is to delete the record dynamically.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically ?

Comment: using a job or scheduler

Comment: where was it posted in question ?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense on why this was down voted,but i appreciate you leaving a comment

Comment: this is a duplicate question only try not to anwer..it