# Delete a row from a database table after a certain time period

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm working on a database driven website and i'm using WAMP 
is it possible with mysql to automatically delete a row from the table below when the registrationDate is old by - for example - a month? 
Thank you

```
 ID  |  Name     |  registrationDate    
 1   |  client1  |  2017-05-09 05:23:16
 2   |  client2  |  2017-05-11 12:13:30
```

Comment: Quick answer:  yes, it is possible.  If you want something more detailed, please post the code you have tried and we can try to assist further.

Comment: see [How to delete a MySQL record after a certain time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an event eg:

```
CREATE EVENT deleteEachMonth
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
-- !!! no *END*: will continue until you explicitly drop the event
DO 
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_date <  DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

in your case

```
CREATE EVENT deleteEachMonth 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-05-01 00:00:00' 
DO 
DELETE FROM client WHERE registrationDate < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: wrong (   before DATE:SUB .. answer  updated ..

Comment: Wrong starting data too (101 instead  of 01)  .. answer  updated ..

Comment: You have a wrong (  before DATE_SUB  .. answer  updated with (hope)  correct code