# How to run a void if went to the next day C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to write a software in C#. I want to know how my software will do something everytime the time went to next day. (I want to delete all row in a table run by MySql in the next day)

My way is storing the date in a variable `X` when start the program, and use a timer to check every 1 min, `if DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") != X`, call the function. But I hope there is a better way to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: The best approach is to create console application to perform the action and configure it to be used by scheduled job. Schedule the job to run every day at specific time. That way you won't need to worry about current date and time and comaring it.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/

Comment: I agree with @ChetanRanpariya that the best way to do this with C# is by using Windows Scheduler to run a console application. But why don't you use MySQL Event Scheduler instead, and do all the work on the back-end? [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14096429/4934172).

Comment: I agree with @AhmedAbdelhameed regarding an Event. Running software is timezone dependent. What happens if you run it in two different timezones? You would have to implement extra logic in your code to convert time to your servers timezone. If you have an event on the server, that triggers when the **server** ticks into the next day, you remove the need to have extra logic. Just my 2c.

Comment: @DeeKayy90 It is unlikely that a scheduler (irrespective of form) and database would be running in two different data centres let alone time zones

Comment: @MickyD +1 Yeap, unlikely - but possible. I simply pose this as a reason for handling the process on the database, rather than by application :) You do have a good point though!

Answer (score 0):

Leave the data there and have a column that contains the date it was added. When you retrieve the data have a where clause that looks at that date column. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateAdded >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: OP is asking how to _schedule_ the job, not _what to do_ when the time arrives.  Yours could possibly require multiple executions.  Also, OP wants to delete data

Comment: @MickyD He said: "But I  hope there is a better way to do it." This is the better way.

Comment: Perhaps, meanwhile his database size grows at an alarming rate

Comment: @MickyD You have a job that clears out anything older than 2 days. Don't care when it runs.