# How can I make MySQL automatically delete records of a table when date of deletion is specified in each record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made the following table in MySQL:

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> desc NeoTec_test;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Product_Key | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Validation  | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Expiry      | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from NeoTec_test;
+-------------+------------+------------+
| Product_Key | Validation | Expiry     |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| GF427DHH5   | 2017-11-16 | 2017-11-17 |
| GFHJV75HG   | 2017-11-16 | 2017-11-18 |
| GFJYFRTV5   | 2017-11-16 | 2017-11-20 |
+-------------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now coming to the point, I need some help with a part of my project. I want MySQL to automatically delete the Product keys that have expired, i.e., I want to get the product keys deleted automatically on their expiry dates given under the "Expiry" Column of the table. How can I do so? I am a total newbie to MySQL events so I would appreciate the full code... Thank you! :-)

Earlier research I did was not fruitful, but I did found this, which was half helpful...:
[How to delete a MySQL record after a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time)

Comment: Schedule a query which does `DELETE FROM NeoTec_test WHERE NOW() > Expiry`.  By the way, another option for you to consider is to use soft deletion.  With soft deletion, you would add a column to the table which keeps track of whether the data is logically deleted or not, but you wouldn't actually remove the records.  This can have benefits of leaving all your data in one place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) to perform the task like below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT eventName
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
STARTS 'Some Date to start'
ENDS 'End date If any' 

DO
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM NeoTec_test WHERE NOW() > Expiry
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thete is no functionality in mysql to automatically delete a record. You need to trigger the deletion either through a scheduler (mysql's as shown in the question you found, or an external scheduler such as cron), or via a database trigger.

The latter one is probably an overkill.

I would use a scheduler set to a convenient interval based on your business requirements to clean up the table.