# Increase column value at a fix date in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a holiday application software. And in my country Germany every employee at 01.January gets 30 vacation days. So the user table has a column vacation days. So how should I automatically increase the number of vacation days at January first at 00:01 am :) . The same goes for March 31. All the holidays from last year those were not taken till this date, will expire automatically. What's the best way to do that. In the datebase itself or in the java code?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323012/how-can-i-make-mysql-automatically-delete-records-of-a-table-when-date-of-deleti is methioned an event schedluer for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This site will answer your question: [Working with MySQL Scheduled Event](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

In a nutshell you'll need to create an event:

```
CREATE EVENT event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
STARTS DATE("1970-01-101 00:01:00")
DO
   event body
```

You will have to put your update in the *event body* part.

Comment: ok. Where should I put this code. Or should I just execute it in the SQL Editor

Comment: Execute in SQL editor. It's like creating a table, view or trigger.

Comment: aha. And can I see it like I can see a table or stored procedure ?

Comment: I don't know which editor you're using but you can always run the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command.

Comment: and I think I will need a loop. Every user in table USER  needs his column vacationDays incremented by 30 on January 1st