# Error in SQL syntax when creating event to delete session

Tags: mysql, session, session-cookies

I've made slight modifications to the SQL code provided in an answer to this question: [How to delete a MySQL record after a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time)
However, I get a "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error each time I run the query.

```
create event delete_session
on schedule at current_timestamp + interval 1 day
on completion preserve
do begin
  delete from session where date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS);
end;
```

The code should create an event to delete entries from the session table after 7 days, but instead gives me this error. Is there actually a problem with the syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CREATE EVENT` command and `DELETE` command is using the `;` as delimiter. So your `CREATE EVENT` command is ending after the `DELETE` command (before `END`). You need to set the `DELIMITER` at the beginning to use another one on the `CREATE EVENT` command.

```
-- set the DELIMITER to "|"
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT delete_session
    ON schedule AT current_timestamp + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM session WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END |

-- set the DELIMITER back to the default.
DELIMITER ;
```

... and you need to change one more thing:

- remove the trailing `S` on `DAYS`.

Comment: FWIW, `date` is a keyword, but not a _reserved_ keyword. It should be fine to use it without back-ticks.