# Delete records in table after specific period of time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using MySQL as a database for my application, my backend server is Nodejs, I have a query to insert records in a table and each record has to insert date. my problem I want to delete this record after two hours of inserting the date.

```
 function setValue(sql) {
    id = sql;
    connection.query("SELECT subject_group_id,date FROM attendance WHERE subject_group_id = ?", [id], function (err, row) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (row.length > 0) {
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'Attendnace already exists' })
      } else {
        connection.query("INSERT INTO attendance (date,status,subject_group_id) VALUES (NOW(),?,?) ", [ status, id], function (err, row) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            res.send({ 'created': true, 'alert': 'Attendnace had been created successfully' });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I used NOW() to insert the current date in the table for column date, so after two hours of this date **I want this record to be deleted automatically without performing any action.**

I think it can be achieved by adding a new column called expired and inserting statement insert date 2 hours ahead of the current date and then delete statement will do the comparison and delete the record based on this comparison. but my problem how to make the record delete automatically without submitting anything.

Comment: I think your requirement is same as this. Please follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara thank you so much as I am beginner first time heard about event and i guess is the best way to do this

Comment: Consider whether you really want to 'hard delete' data in this way

Comment: you can schedule a cron job as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71649849/16985741)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### multiple ways

- you can opt for `setTimeout` in js, the problem is when service goes down the last set of records won't be deleted
- you can try scheduling inside mysql itself as well https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-syntax.html

Comment: thank you, i think using the second way will be more easier, can you help me with that as in my table i will have date record and i want to make it after two hors of date set to deleted: i foudnd this way to do it but how to apply it for time instead of date `CREATE  PROCEDURE DeleteRows()
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, DateColum), GETDATE())) >= 1
END`