# how to delete a record of a collection after a specific amount of time

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, settimeout, ttl

i want to create an OTP (one time password) for my node js application using mongodb as database
after generating otp and sending that for client with email i want to store the otp as hashedOTP in database and delete (or expire) that after a specific amount of time like 2 minutes
but iam having some problem with that and i dont know how to do it
i have read some articles and mongodb documentations about TTL but i didn't understand that how its working at all and i guess its just about date type records
so i did it with js setTimeout method and in small scales its working fine but because iam not experienced i dont know that it work fine with biger scales or not
here is my schema that i made and i tried expires and expiresAfterSeconds for hashedOTP but it didnt worked

```
const adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName : {
    type : 'string'
},
lastName : {
    type : 'string'
},
email : {
    type : 'string'
},
password : {
    type : 'string'
},
phoneNumber : {
    type : 'string'
},
role : {
    type : 'string'
},
confirmationToken : {
    type : 'string'
},
hasConfirmedEmail : {
    type : Boolean,
    default : false
},
hashedOTP : {
    type : 'string',
}
```

})

now the first question is saving OTP in database is correct way?
here is my code for handling with setTimeout

```
    try {
    const hashedotp = await bcrypt.hash(otp,10)
    verifiedAdmin.hashedOTP = hashedotp
    await verifiedAdmin.save()
    setTimeout(async () => {
        console.log('set time out gonna work now ')
        verifiedAdmin.hashedOTP = ''
        await verifiedAdmin.save()
    }, 120000);
```

i know that it is not necessary to hash the otp but i just did it and the verifiedAdmi is the user that i want to send otp for it and its made by above schema
i just feel that this setTimeout is not going to work fine cause it has many interactions with database

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the hashedOTP after a fixedTime (ie 120000 second) , You could run a cron job and update the collection by checking against the createdAt time

1 - Run Cron Job

2 - if( time of checking is greater than createdAt + 120000 sec) then delete
the hashotp

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

 new CronJob({
    cronTime: "00 */5 * * * *", //every five minutes
    onTick: function() {
       helperFunctionToUpdateData()         
    },
}),
```

i prefer using moment.js to check time difference

Comment: thanks for your answer but the main problem is that i want to have less interaction with database but i forgot to mention that in this way yet we have much interactions with database

Comment: setTimout is queuing those code to be run later , so in case your server gets restarted due  to any reasons , the setTimout will be disappeared and the token won't be removed from the database which is not ideal when thinking from the security part. Its best to implement something like cronJob

Comment: that's the main issue, when the server restarted you loose the action in the setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting you do do the below:

Create a different model let say , `OtpVerification` with fields `userId` (indexed, because lot of searching will be done), **otp** (the random number) and `expiresAt` (current time + 10 minutes can be done easily using moment js).

Then while verifying find in `OTPVerification` if any document with that `userId` present if present check `otp` and

```
if (expiresAt > currentTime) {
   // allow 
} else {
   // otp expired
}
```