# How to Delete Records after certain time passes in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Good evenings, sirs. I wonder how can i delete records in Sequelize after certain time passes? For example, I want to delete unauthorized records after 10 days.I am new to Sequelize so if you can give me an idea, i will be very thankful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time Depending on your use case, a CRON job might be what you need. This is not part of sqlize library though.

Comment: @mattdevio Appreciate,sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will not run automatically unless you run that manually, So, You should have to use cron job, it will run your code every time you specified

Here, An example of how can you start a cron job.

// Importing required libraries

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
const express = require("express");
app = express(); // Initializing app
```

// Creating a cron job that runs every 10-second

https://crontab.guru/    // where you can check cron time

```
cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *", function() {
     console.log("running a task every 10 second");
     // write your login here, delete your records
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think below code will help you to achieve this. Here the example is showing to delete data after 24 hours. Hope this will help you.

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

await ExampleTable.destroy({
    where: {
        createdAt: {[Op.lte]: new Date(Date.now() - (60*60*24*1000))}
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,sir. But i wonder do i need to use this with cronjob? Or it works by itself?