# how to add expire time to verification code nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

how can i add expire time to this verification code .
i want to delete it after 10 min from database .

```
var fourcode = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
```

```
app.post("/sendforgetpassword", async (req, res)=> {
    const email = req.body.email
    
    database.query('SELECT * FROM verifications WHERE email ="' + email + '"', function(err, result) {
      if (!err)  {
      console.log(result[0]);
   
      if (result.length > 0) {
          var fourcode = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
  
          if(result[0].code == null ){
              var sent = sendEmail(email, fourcode);
              if (sent != '0') {
                  var data = {
                      code: fourcode
                  }
                  connection.query('UPDATE verifications SET ? WHERE email ="' + email + '"', data, function(err, result) {
                      console.log(data);
                    if(err) console.log(err); 
                  })
                  res.send('The code has been sent to your email address' )
              } 
              else {
                  res.send('Something goes to wrong. Please try again')
              }
          }
          else {
            res.send('the code is already sent to your email')
        } 
      } 
      else {
          console.log('2');
          res.send('he Email is not registered with us')
  
      }}
      else console.log(err);
  })
    })
```

Comment: take reference from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096429/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-after-a-certain-time

Comment: You should **NEVER** pass an unescaped string from a client to a SQL database. This allows [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which makes it possible to allow everyone to drop or alter the database completly.

Comment: @Christopher what do you mean ?

Comment: add expires_at field to table and you need to consider using a framework like prisma

Comment: i already add expire filed to table

Comment: check if the expiry date is passed when validating the code. 
as for the deleting from database, you need to make a cron job that runs every specific amount of time to remove the expired codes.

Comment: @husam in your first 4 lines (including the empty one) you already create the opportunity to pass this as a request: `no one cares" OR "1`. This will result in a SQL query: `WHERE email = "no one cares" OR "1"` -- and this will affect all rows.

Comment: @Christopher can u give me the solution ?

Comment: Use the same method with the params as you did in your 2nd query and update that one too. If you are using mysql or mysql2, this will do it: `db.query("... SET code = ?, expire_at = date_add(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) WHERE email = ?", [fourcode, email], (...) => {});` (based on the update query)

Comment: @Christopher i mean u said i have vulnerability (SQL injections ) what should i do to cover it ?

Comment: @husam you just need to change the way how you send variables with your query. [npm:mssql package has a hint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection) and the [npm:mysql package too](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values). In my comment above, i already showed how you can solve it if you use mysql package.

Comment: @Christopher i did this `db.query("... SET code = ?, expire_at = date_add(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) WHERE email = ?", [fourcode, email], (...) => {}); `  but after that time the fourcode still in database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250795/discussion-between-husam-and-christopher).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate code by using the npm packages like **speakeasy**, which is used to create OTP, you can also set valid time(TTL) to that generated OTP.

```
import * as speakeasy from 'speakeasy';

export const SPEAKEASY_CONFIG = {
  step: 600,
  digits: 4,
  window: 6,
  length: 20,
  encoding: 'base32'
};

const secretekey = 'test-secretkey';

function generateOtp(secreteKey: string) {
  return speakeasy.totp({
    secret: secreteKey,
    step: SPEAKEASY_CONFIG.step,
    digits: SPEAKEASY_CONFIG.digits,
    encoding: SPEAKEASY_CONFIG.encoding
  });
}

function verifyOtp(secret: string, otp: string) {
  return speakeasy.totp.verify({
    secret,
    token: otp,
    step: SPEAKEASY_CONFIG.step,
    digits: SPEAKEASY_CONFIG.digits,
    encoding: SPEAKEASY_CONFIG.encoding
  });
}
```

Here the property **step** defines the time(How long generated OTP should be valid). property **step** value should be in seconds.

If you want to more about the npm package **speakeasy**, check the below link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy

Answer (score 0):

```
const moment = require('moment');

// Generate OTP with timestamp
function generateOTP() {
    const otp = generateRandomOTP(); // Replace with your OTP generation logic
    const timestamp = moment(); // Current timestamp
    return { otp, timestamp };
}

// Verify OTP and check expiration
function verifyOTP(userOTP, storedOTP, expirationDurationInMinutes = 5) {
    const currentTimestamp = moment();
    const storedTimestamp = moment(storedOTP.timestamp);

    if (currentTimestamp.diff(storedTimestamp, 'minutes') <= expirationDurationInMinutes) {
        if (userOTP === storedOTP.otp) {
            return true; // OTP is valid and not expired
        }
    }
    return false; // OTP is either invalid or expired
}

// Example usage
const generatedOTP = generateOTP();
console.log('Generated OTP:', generatedOTP.otp);
console.log('Timestamp:', generatedOTP.timestamp.format());

// Simulate OTP verification
const userEnteredOTP = '123456'; // Replace with the actual OTP entered by the user
const isOTPValid = verifyOTP(userEnteredOTP, generatedOTP);

if (isOTPValid) {
    console.log('OTP is valid and not expired.');
} else {
    console.log('OTP is either invalid or expired.');
}
```

---

In this Node.js example:

We use the moment library to work with timestamps and calculate the time difference.

generateOTP generates an OTP and associates it with the current timestamp using moment.

verifyOTP takes the user-entered OTP, the stored OTP with its timestamp, and an expiration duration in minutes. It checks if the OTP matches and if the timestamp falls within the specified expiration duration.

Make sure to replace the generateRandomOTP() placeholder with your actual OTP generation logic, and adjust the expirationDurationInMinutes variable to match your security requirements.

---