# Delete MySQL Row after 30 minutes using Cron Jobs/Event Scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, cron, row

I am quite the noob at MySQL and PHP/Cron Jobs so if you all could explain it easily as in where to put the event, etc, that'd be great, anyways, on with the question.

Question: I have a table called my_Table and it has an entry with 3 fields: name,age,timestamp. So one row has this for instance. Sam | 20 | whateverthetimeis.
Now, when that row reaches 30 minutes old, I want it to be deleted, same with any other rows that hit 30 minutes, thank you all for the help, I have read the other answers but like I said I'm still a beginner and dont quite understand what people are answering. Thanks for the help

If I can do this with a Cron Job or a MySQL Event (I don't know how to set an event up) it would be great for anyone to help! :D

My code for deleting after 30 minutes (Deletes all rows even when they aren't 30 minutes old)

```
<?php
include_once('../config.php');

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);



$runpurge = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE");






?>
```

the main display code:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cw_LFG ORDER BY `time` DESC ") or die(mysql_error);



while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo strip_tags($row['cname']);
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['level'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo strip_tags($row['region']);
    echo "</td><td width='100px'>";
    echo timeElapsed(strtotime($row['time']));
    echo "</td><td style='word-wrap: break-word'>";
    echo strip_tags($row['comment']);
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";



}

echo "</table>";
$curtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$curtimestr = strtotime($curtime);
function timeElapsed($time) {
    $elapsedTime = time() - $time;

    if ($elapsedTime < 1) {
        return 'Right now';
    }
    if ($elapsedTime < 60){
        return '< 1 Minute ago';
    }
```

Comment: Possible match: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216279/delete-whole-row-after-x-mins-in-mysql-db-and-php/7216515#7216515`

Comment: I know you're a beginner, but you still need to put some work into it. Please show what you've tried writing, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @MohitBhansali I would like mine to be automatic, what you sent doesn't really help me :/

Comment: @Barmar I haven't tried writing anything yet because I don't know what to put in the cron php file :/

is it something like DELETE FROM my_table AFTER 30*60

Comment: Use `AJAX` in your program. And start writing code.

Comment: @MohitBhansali AJAX is not relevant. This is a periodic server script, not a web page.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL would be

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

Write a PHP script that executes this SQL, and add a crontab entry that runs it every 30 minutes. Or use the MySQL Event Scheduler to run it periodically; it is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).

Comment: It didn't work, could it be because I have all my times converted to UNIX?

Comment: What datatype is `timestamp`? I assumed it was either `timestamp` or `datetime`, so everything operates in the server's timezone.

Comment: It's type is timestamp, basically I have it so it converts the time into UNIX and displays it that way to the users, in sort of a x minutes ago type display

Comment: When you add rows to the table, do you set the timestamp column to `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: Then I can't think of any reason why my code didn't work. Everything operates in the server's timezone.

Comment: Hmmm, so I have your code in a PHP file called purging.php, and then I added a cronjob that runs every minute with this command `/public_html/mysite/cron/purging.php`

Is that not how I do it or :o

Comment: You didn't just put my code in the script, you wrapped it in calls using the PDO, mysqli, or mysql extension, right?

Comment: oh, no I didn't do that, don't know how to do that ;c

Comment: Then it's time for you to learn. I'm not going to write a whole PHP script for you, there are plenty of tutorials. Google PDO.

Comment: Google "pdo tutorial". I haven't read any of them (I just read documentation, I rarely use tutorials), so I can't make specific recommendations.

Comment: I made the script and got it working, but instead of deleting things that are 30 minutes old, it deletes everything :c

Comment: You should always test `DELETE` queries with `SELECT` first, to make sure it will process the rows you want. But I really don't see how my query could do that if you're properly filling in the `timestamp` table and not changing it after the row is created. Does the column have an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option?

Comment: Actually, that option should make it delete _fewer_ rows. The query is really simple, it means exactly what it says -- delete the rows whose timestamp is earlier than 30 minutes ago. Edit your question and post the contents of the PHP script.

Comment: Ah, I think my problem here is, even though it's a `TIMESTAMP`, my script that displays the time actually converts it into UNIX time, so I went ahead and changed what you provided to this `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1800)"`. I also turned on the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option after searching around to see what people did! If this works then I will tell you in 7 minutes! If not then I will update with my code, tell me though about what I did with the UNIX if that seems like it would do the right thing, thanks! :D

Comment: I'm at a loss. What do you see if you do `select * from my_table` before running the deletion script?

Comment: When I run `select * from my_table` it shows every field as expected

Comment: How about `select * from my_table where timestamp < now() - interval 30 minute`?

Comment: Make that: `select now(), * from my_table where timestamp < now() - interval 30 minute`

Comment: Updated main post with more code, will try what you just said

Comment: Nothing is echo'd when I use that ^ O_o

Comment: When I echo `select * from my_table where timestamp < now() - interval 30 minute` it says Resource Id #3

Comment: This makes no sense. If nothing is echoed when you run that select, then nothing should be deleted when you run the delete with the same WHERE clause.  Do you have two different columns, `time` and `timestamp`? Or are you just copying them differently into your question?

Comment: You can't echo queries, I meant for you to do it interactively, either with the `mysql` CLI tool or PHP My Admin.

Comment: To see the result of a query in PHP, you have to use code like your display code.

Comment: Oh? Now I'm getting confused, and the column that has my timestamps is called time that's why I'm changing it, or is that not what I'm supposed to do, and I'll do the phpmyadmin way to view a query, I guess I was just being dumb

Comment: Ah, when I run that query up their `select * from cw_LFG where time < now() - interval 30 minute` it shows a total of 4 rows, 3 of which are over 30 minutes old, and one which is only 1 minute old

Comment: And this one: `select now(), * from cw_LFG where time < now() - interval 30 minute` shows a Syntax error

Comment: any help @Barmar? I feel like im running around in circles

Comment: @user2540796 YOu should be updating your question with this new information, not putting it in a comment.

Comment: *"Just beware of daylight savings changes, a change forward one hour will kill all your sessions instantaneously."* – [Joachim Isaksson Dec 17 at 8:12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628957/deleting-item-from-database-after-30-minutes/20628984#comment30875806_20628984)