# deleting item from database after 30 minutes

Tags: mysql

I want to have a script, that counts how many users are online on my site, but this script should count guests, so I have created a database for session, this script gives user an ID and set 30 minutes session, and now I have a problem, because if he is not active more than 30 minutes, he should be deleted from the database, because I want to count by ID how many users are online, and I have headache how can I do this.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by Barmar in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415608/delete-mysql-row-after-30-minutes-using-cron-jobs-event-scheduler/17415700#17415700):

> ```
> DELETE FROM my_table
> WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
> ```
>
> Write a PHP script that executes this SQL, and add a crontab entry
>   that runs it every 30 minutes. Or use the MySQL Event Scheduler to run
>   it periodically; it is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).

Comment: you can execute this query just before an user would see the counter of online users.

Comment: Just beware of daylight savings changes, a change forward one hour will kill all your sessions instantaneously.

Comment: @sergio If you run it every 30 minutes, some sessions could take up to 1 hour long (in the case a write is performed just after a deletion). And in the best case scenario (a write is made just before a deletion, which is as difficult as the opposite) you'll get 30 minute long sessions. As a result, your sessions will be an average of 45 minute long.

Comment: @jackflash, I want to update session after time you go to new page, for example you click on contact.html, then the session is updating by NOW() :)

Comment: Use something like this : "UPDATE session SET start=NOW() WHERE id='%s'", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($session_id)

Comment: @user3110241 Yes, that's what I meant with a "write". If you want minute-accuracy you should perform the deletion every 90 seconds.

Comment: Direct copy/paste from another user's answer ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415700/338665)) is generally frowned upon. At least rewrite it in your own words. If you don't want to do that, link back to the original post instead of copy/paste (so there is a canonical reference point). Otherwise you're just taking credit for another's work, and diluting the content...

Comment: Edited. thanks. I will do it for the future.

Comment: @sergio, you must be joking. I'm now flagging "your" answers. *"I will do it for the future"* - Do you  expect from us to clean after you or what do you want to say by *"future"*?

Comment: @hakre I this case I found the answer but did not know that it should be set the source. Now I know it

Comment: @sergio: It's not about *source*, it's about that you duplicate content. That scatters up the site. Leave a comment with a link to the duplicate question/answer if you think it's fitting. Sure that does not get you any reputation but it's how this site works.

Comment: @hakre. Now it clear for me. But I thought it better to show at once the answer. Ok, no problem.

Comment: @hakre "I will do it for the future" means that if there isset the answer I will just set the url to this answer

Comment: @sergio: Now clean up the mess you've left on the site. You can delete "your" answers. In case it's accepted and you can't delete it, ask moderators to help you flagging the question as a duplicate (tell them what the duplicate question was) and then ask them to delete your answer.

Comment: @sergio: Create a list of the answers you've duplicated and [**add them to the chat**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44164/discussion-between-sergio-and-hakre). Also make visible from where you've copied that. I'll then feel invited to take a look if you like.

Comment: I will check it, because there is a chance that there are no duplicate answer except this.

Comment: That chance is pretty much around zero. The oppsite is more the case, there is a chance that you copied a lot of answers.

Comment: Ok, I will check. No problem. Thank for good remark

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned any database in specific, I give you a general idea of how to implement it:

You can have a table like this:

```
USER_SESSIONS
(
  USER_ID //UNIQUE_ID
  LAST_ACTIVE //TIMESTAMP
)
```

Here is the functionality you can associate to implement the session:

1. When a user logs in, you create an entry in this table.
2. When a user logs out, you delete the corresponding entry from this table.
3. When user does some activity (depends on how you want to track activity in the front end), update the corresponding TIMESTAMP of the user.
4. Create a DB Schedule (a continuously running process) that monitors the TIMESTAMP column. All good databases have a built in scheduler. Here is some *pseudo code* for the scheduler:

```
FOR each entry in USER_SESSIONS
 If (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LAST_ACTIVE) > [30 mins]  then
    delete the entry of the corresponding user from this table.
    //This will essentially cause a session timeout.
 End If
LOOP;
```

I hope you got a fair idea of how to implement it.